# Spring boot application.properties naming

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, datasource, application.properties

I am learning about springboot and trying to connect to a DB2 database.  I got that working just fine.

Below are my working DB2 properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://server:port/database:currentSchema=schema-name;
spring.datasource.username=user1
spring.datasource.password=password1
```

But I renamed them to start with "db2" instead "spring" like:

```
db2.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://server:port/database:currentSchema=schema-name;
db2.datasource.username=user1
db2.datasource.password=password1
```

My app still runs, hHowever, when I do that, my controllers no longer return results as they did before the rename.

The reason I ask this is that if I add 2nd data source in the future, I could distinguish easily properties by their data sources if I name them like this.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @Kosta Tenasis answer below and this article (https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/multiple-data-sources-with-spring-boot/), I was able to resolve and figure this out.

Then going back to my specific question, once you have the configuration for data source in place, you can then modify application.properties to have:

```
db2.datasource.url=...
```

instead of having:

```
spring.datasource.url=...
```

**NOTE1**: if you are using Springboot 2.0, they changed to use Hikari and Hikari does not have `url` property but instead uses `jdbc-url`, so just change above to:

```
db2.datasource.jdbc-url=...
```

**NOTE2:** In your datasource that you had to create when adding multiple datasources to your project, you will have annotation `@ConfigurationProperties`.  This annotation needs to point to your updated application.properties for datasource (the `db2.datasource.url`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Spring looks for `spring.datasource.**` for the properties of the `DataSource` to connect to.

So you might be getting wrong results because you are not connecting to the database. If you want to configure a DataSource with different,from default, properties you can do like so

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="db2.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                            .build();
}
```

And let's say a day comes along and you want a second `DataSource` you can modify the previous class to something like:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="db2.datasource")
public DataSource d2Datasource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                            .build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="db3.datasource")
public DataSource db3Datasource() { //pun intented
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                            .build();
    }
}
```

and after that in each `Class` that you want a `DataSource` you can specify which of the beans you like:

```
public class DB3DependedClass{
    
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public DB3DependedClass(@Qualifier("db3Datasource") DataSource dataSource){
           this.dataSource = dataSource;
 
    }
}
```

So by default spring will look for

1. `spring.datasource.url (or spring.datasource.jdbc-url)`
2. `spring.datasource.username`
3. `spring.datasource.password`

If you specify another `DataSource` of your own, those values are not needed.

So in the above example where we specified let's say `db3.datasource` spring will look for

1. `db3.datasource.url`
2. `db3.datasource.username`
3. `db3.datasource.password`

Important thing here is that the `spring` **IS NOT** inferred meaning the **complete path** is indeed: `db3.datasource.url`
and **NOT**
`spring.db3.datasource.url`

Finally to wrap this up you do have the flexibility to make it start with `spring` if you want so by declaring a prefix like `spring.any.path.ilike.datasouce` and of course under that the related values. Spring will pick up either path as long as you specify it.

NOTE: This answer is written solely in the text box provided here and was not tested in an IDE for compilation errors. The logic still holds though

Comment: Thank you.  So, if I want spring to pick up settings, these properties (data source related ones) have to start with "spring....."; otherwise, I have to create custom configurations like you explained above.  Did I get that right?  Thank you

Comment: I will add the answer to this as explanation to my answer to be more visible. You are most welcome

Comment: Thank you.  Would you be able to recommend a good tsource to learn little bit about this?

Comment: There are multiple things adressed in the answer above.. One is the bean management, how we used quilifier to specify what bean to use(since for the same type there were 2 beans) you can read a little bit here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-names and the datasource part which you can read here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-data-source-programmatic. Consider accepting the answer if it was the solution to you question.

Comment: Do you mind commenting on this SO please and thank you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72296481/spring-boot-hibernate-error-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null-when